# UIWebView: where to load request in tab screen? viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Tags: uiwebview, viewdidload, tabbarcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a tab bar controller, one tab screen contains a web view, loading a request say google.com, when it is loading(ie before the didload delegate method call of webview), if I switch to another tab and then go back, the spinner is still running but the page is never loaded, I guess viewDidLoad is only called once, so should I put the loading code in viewDidAppear, or is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to refresh the WebView everytime it appears. But use `- (void)viewWillAppear:animated`

Edit:

OK, since ive got more info now, i can give you more info!

In your .h:

`BOOL *loaded`

in your .m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:animated {
     if (loaded == NO) {
         //load the website
     }
 }


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
     [loaded setBool:YES];
 }


- (IBAction)loadWebsite {
    //if the user reloads or loads a new website do this:
    [loaded setBool:NO];
    //reload, or load the new website
}
```

To load, or reload your UITableView:

```
 NSString *urlAddress = urltextfield.text;
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Clarification: I am setting the BOOL to YES if the View is loaded, so when the webview has finished loading and the user switches to the other tab, and back the WebView doesn't get reloaded. But if the WebView isn't fully loaded the BOOl returns NO, and the WebView will get reloaded! When the WebView gets reloaded or a new Website gets loaded im setting the BOOL to NO, and that loops over and over! Note that BOOls are NO by default.

Comment: Because if the request is not loaded fully and I switch to another tab screen, then it stops loading, when I go back to the tab it shows me an empty webview.

Comment: ok then set a BOOL to YES when your WebView has finished loading, and in your viewWillAppear method do `if (yourBool == NO) //reload` and set the BOOL to NO when you start to load the WebView. I will add this to my answer too, i hope this helps.

Comment: OK i have added all what you need to my answer, please check out the updated post now!

Comment: Thanks, but how to I actually reload a website in a uiwebview?

Comment: you probably have a URL textField, so just load the UIWebView with the url entered in the TextField.

Comment: I have added code on how to load a uitableview. But LEARN how to use google! I got that last bit of code from google! Just enter in google what you are searching for (ex. "uiwebview tutorial", "load webview"...) it can't be that hard!?